# Размытие с использованием CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, filter

Как добиться такого эффекта для блока? Пробовал через св-ва `filter: blur();` и `opacity`, но не получается.

[image: Рисунок 1 - Изображение блока из Adobe XD]

Comment: Создай дополнительный слой  с той же картинкой, вот его и заблюрь..... И будет так как хочешь

Comment: @Air, выделенный слой - не картинка

Comment: я понял... Вот я и говорю, что в css это делается так...

Comment: @Air, а, хорошо. Спасибо Вам

Answer (score 4):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.layer-one {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/6206/43810070.8/0_5c834_17e56af9_orig);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
}

.layer-two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 115px;
  left: 125px;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-image: url(https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/6206/43810070.8/0_5c834_17e56af9_orig);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -125px -115px;
  background-size: auto;
  filter: blur(15px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="layer-one"></div>
  <div class="layer-two"></div>
</div>
```

---

Есть еще вариант `backdrop-filter: blur();`, проще и удобнее, но не все браузеры поддерживают.

[Подробнее тут...](https://webref.ru/css/backdrop-filter)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/6206/43810070.8/0_5c834_17e56af9_orig);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.blur-layer {
  position: absolute;
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="blur-layer"></div>
</div>
```